# assert a json field that contans a dot

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have a json response that outputs the following:

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "request.xxx": [
      "The field xxx must be between xxx and xxx."
    ],
    "request.xxx": [
      "The field xxx must be between xxx and xxx."
    ],
    "request.xxx[0].xxx": [
      "The field xxx must be between xxx and xxx."
    ]
  }
}
```

Now usually in script assertion we would find levels in a json by entering the field name of the json separated by a . As an example if I want to find `request.xxxHotelId`, to find it I will go `def xxxhotelid = json.modelState.request.xxxrHotelId`.

But as you can see the problem is the . in between `request` and `xxxHotelID`. Because there's a ., it would think `request` and `xxxHotelID` are on different levels so it would not find this field within the response.

My question is how to find the field `request.xxxHotelId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as easy as

```
def juniperhotelid = json.modelState.'request.JuniperHotelId'
```

Comment: You can also use the map subscript notation `json.modelState['request.JuniperHotelId']`